# xsl - tag position with text mixed in parent

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

In XSL 1.0, I am trying to distinguish between the following 2 scenarios which both occur within the input XML I need to process and each to be handled differently.

Scenario 1

```
<tag1><tag2/> some text</tag1>
```

Scenario 2

```
<tag1>some text <tag2/></tag1>
```

I have a template which matches at the `<tag2/>` level, within this I want scenario 1 to ignore `<tag2/>`, in scenario 2 I want to insert a `<br/>` in place of `<tag2/>`.

I have searched on here and on google but can't seem to figure out how to distinguish based on the position of `<tag2/>` within `<tag1>`.

I have looked into **preceding-sibling** and **generate-id** and tried to use something like:-

```
 not(
    generate-id(
       preceding-sibling::node()[1]
    )
  = generate-id(
       preceding-sibling::text()[1]
    )
 )
```

and the

```
position()
```

of `<tag2/>` doesn't seem to help here either as both appear to be operating at the node level??

Any ideas would be welcomed?

Thanks
Roger

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simpler, easier and more fundamental solution than the currently accepted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="tag2[preceding-sibling::text()]">
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On this input:

```
<items>
    <tag1><tag2/>some text</tag1>
    <tag1>some text <tag2/></tag1>
</items>
```

Produces:

```
some text
some text <br/>
```

A more complex solution would require additional information about the desired output.

Comment: ok thanks for the quick response, I think this is enough for now, I'll give this a go...

Comment: On running again I realised my input xml had a text() in both scenarios, in the first scenario this was due to a new line between tags. so '<tag1>\n<tag2/>', but with your solution; adding in tag2[preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space(string(.))]] has resolved this now. Again thanks for the help!

Comment: @MrChick: `tag2[preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space()]]` would be enough. Also take a look to @Dimitre's answer and mine for streamable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these **patterns**:

```
node()[1]
```

This match first node child.

```
node()[1][self::tag2]
```

This match first node child which is also a `tag2` element.

```
node()[not(self::text()[not(normalize-space())])][1][self::tag2]
```

This match first node child which is not a whitespace only text node and also a `tag2` element (in case you preserve whitespace only text node as you should with XHTML input).

I give you this approach because the first and second patterns are [streamable](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-21/#streamable-patterns) (`preceding` axis is not streamable).

**Note**: The second must be rewrite as `node()[position() = 1 and self::tag2]`.

Answer (score 0):

**A simpler and more fundamental solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "node()[self::tag2 and position()=1]"/>
 <xsl:template match=
  "node()[self::tag2 and position()=2]">
  <br/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<tag1><tag2/> some text</tag1>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<tag1> some text</tag1>
```

**When applied on this document**:

```
<tag1>some text <tag2/></tag1>
```

**again the wanted, correct answer is produced**:

```
<tag1>some text <br/>
</tag1>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule (template) copies every node as-is.
2. The first template that is overriding the identity rule matches any node whose name is `tag2` and whose position in the node-list is 1. It has no body so the `tag2` element is ignored.
3. The second template that overrides the identity rule is similar to the first, but the position of the matched `tag2` node has to be 2. In this case it is replaced by `<br/>`.

Comment: Yes, I also would go this path because it conforms the new streamable conditions.