# XSLT: mixed text and node - how to replace <b>

Tags: html, regex, xml, xslt

I searched and found this post from about 4 yrs ago:
[xsl - tag position with text mixed in parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606014/xsl-tag-position-with-text-mixed-in-parent/33330114#33330114)
and I am trying to do something simlar, but a little different... but cannot get it to work. How do I change:

```
<tag1>some <tag2>other</tag2> text</tag1>
into:
<tag1>some <bold>other</bold> text</tag1>
```

?

In other words, I have mixed text and nodes, and I want to rename the tag of a node, but keep the correct location within the text.

Comment: Why does this question have a *regex* tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided us any existing XSLT to start with so it's hard to tell you exactly how to fit this into what you have, but basically you need to be correctly using `apply-templates` and matching the elements that you need to swap out:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!-- itentity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- apply templates to contents -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tag2">
    <bold>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </bold>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to your sample input:

```
<tag1>some <tag2>other</tag2> text</tag1>
```

The result is:

```
<tag1>some <bold>other</bold> text</tag1>
```

Comment: Ok, yes... but I am trying to replace also <tag1> with <p> at the same time. Is that doable? So it would become:
<p>some <bold>other</bold> text</p>

Comment: @LC Yes, just follow the same example as what I did for `tag2`. If you can't figure it out, I can show you, but please try it first.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help.